# Get fully-qualified name of an OU

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap, ou

I have a code to get the list of OUs within a domain.

Now this just lists all the OUs and does not give any way to distinguish between an OU and a sub OU.

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain);

DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
mySearcher.Filter = ("(objectClass=organizationalUnit)");

foreach (SearchResult temp in mySearcher.FindAll())
{
   OU_DownList.Items.Add(temp.Properties["name"][0].ToString());
}
```

Is there a way i can get the fully qualified name of an OU?

Something like this for a sub OU:

```
CN=Computer1,OU=Department 101,OU=Business Unit #1,DC=us,DC=xyz,DC=com
```

Any help is appreciated... thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`temp.Path` should get you the distinguishedName of each OU.

Comment: hey thanks  buddy but is there a way to display the above fully qualified name "CN=Computer1,OU=Department 101,OU=Business Unit #1,DC=us,DC=xyz,DC=com" as.. businessunit/department 101

Comment: `string.Join("/",temp.Path.Split(',').Select(s=>s.StartsWith("OU")).Reverse().ToArray())`

Answer (score 1):

Use the property `Path` from `SearchResult`, as in `temp.Path`, see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresult.path(v=vs.80).aspx).

> The Path property uniquely identifies
>   this entry in the Active Directory
>   hierarchy. The entry can always be
>   retrieved using this path.

You can enumerate all the available properties with the following source code:

```
foreach(string propKey in temp.Properties.PropertyNames)
{
    // Display each of the values for the property identified by
    // the property name.
    foreach (object property in temp.Properties[propKey])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", propKey, property.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks so much.. is there a way to display the above string as businessunit/department 101